# Confused About Polynomials on Real Intervals

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $\mathbb{F}$ mean $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ .

I have proved a result (1) that if two polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$ are identical as functions on $\mathbb{F}$ then the polynomials have identical coefficients. I can use this result to prove a second result (2), which is that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$, the vector space of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$, is infinite-dimensional:

**Proof** (by contradiction): Suppose the list of polynomials/vectors $L=(p_1,\ldots{},p_n)$ spans $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$. Let $m$ be the largest degree of any polynomial in $L$. I claim that the polynomial $p':\mathbb{F}\to\mathbb{F}\,\,\,\,\,p'(z)=z^{m+1}$ is not in $\text{span}(L)$. If it were, there would exist field elements $a_1,\ldots{},a_n$ such that $[a_1p_1+
\ldots{}+a_np_n](z)=z^{m+1}$ for all $z\in{}\mathbb{F}$. By (1), the polynomials on both sides of the equation should have identical coefficients. However this is impossible as the polynomial on the left-hand side has coefficient 0 for term $z^{m+1}$ while the polynomial on the right-hand side has coefficient 1 for that term. Therefore the two polynomials are not identical and $p'\not\in{}\text{span}(L)$. Thus $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$ is infinite-dimensional.

---

The vectors/polynomials in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$ are defined on all of $\mathbb{F}$. However, as far as I can tell we could restrict the domain of all the polynomials in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$ to a real interval such as $[0,1]$ and still have a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Let $V$ label this vector space.

**Question**: Does the result (1) still hold for $V$? That is, is it true that if two polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ are identical as functions on $[0,1]$ then the polynomials have identical coefficients? How can I prove it?

Comment: How did you prove (1)? - I think you'll find that you could prove the result provided the polynomials take same values on an infinite set. Then you're done.

Comment: Hello :) Yes, it's true. Moreover, if two univariate or multivariate polynomials are identical as functions on an **open** domain $U$, then the polynomials have the same coefficients. Just look at their derivatives at an arbitrarily chosen point $x_0\in U$ and consider the Taylor series.

Comment: @ancientmathematician By contrapositive. Suppose that a polynomial has some non-zero coefficient. Then I find a particular element of F where the polynomial is non-zero. This proves that if a polynomial evaluates to zero everywhere in F then all its coefficients are zero. It also shows that if two polynomials defined on all of F are identical as functions, then they have identical coefficients. However, the particular field element from the proof is not necessarily in the interval [0,1], so the proof won't work here.

Comment: @Jochen Hello! Sounds interesting. My understanding of Taylor series is almost non-existent. I guess the idea is that the polynomials have Taylor series representations which are unique and somehow the Taylor series coefficients relate to the polynomial coefficients?

Comment: OK @Gary. I would have argued directly that if $f(\alpha)=g(\alpha)$ for all  $\alpha\in S$ where $S$ is any set of size greater than the degree of $f-g$ then $f=g$. Just look at $\phi(x)=f(x)-g(x)=\sum a_i x^i$; we'll have linear equations in the $a_i$ by evaluating at distinct points $\alpha_j\in s$: the determinant is the Vandermonde of the $\alpha_j$ so is non zero so all $a_i=0$.